# Structuring database for e-commerce with multiple variants of items

Tags: php, sql, database, data-structures

How best to organize my SQL tables provided each item for an e-commerce site has multiple variants? I run an electronic cigarette business and things are organized by flavor and strength. Here's a rough mockup of my SQL table:

```
itemNum itemName itemPrice itemConc stockRemaining
--------------------------------------------------
   1     Banana    10.99      0           5       
   2     Banana    10.99      6           42
   3     Banana    10.99      12          12
   4     Banana    10.99      18          0
   5     Cherry    10.99      0           19
   6     Cherry    10.99      6           36
  ...     ...       ...      ...          ...
```

`Banana` and `Cherry` being flavors, with `0`, `6`, `12`, `18` being the strength. When a person adds something to their cart, things are stored in `$_SESSION` data in two arrays: `$productNumbers` and `$productQuantities`, so when someone adds 5x Cherry in 0 strength and 2x Banana in 18 strength to their cart, the following is initialized:

```
$productNumbers[] = {5, 4};
$productQuantities[] = {5, 2};
```

However, this is cumbersome to manage and has too much bloat. I end up with four rows per flavor when I think it could be optimized. I end up needing to add stock for each individual item/strength combo rather than just adding stock to one flavor; I end up having potentially hundreds of rows when I only need 1/4th of that. I was thinking of something like the below:

```
itemNum itemName itemPrice zero six twelve eighteen
---------------------------------------------------
   1     Banana    10.99    0    1     5      2 
   2     Cherry    10.99    6    3     42     3
  ...     ...       ...    ...  ...    ...   ...
```

But I'm not sure how best to implement this. The columns right of `itemPrice` would be stock levels of individual strengths per flavor, but when considering my cart system, how would I differentiate between them? This seems very efficient, but implementation is proving troublesome. I can't think of a way to make it work without doing multiple arrays:

```
$productNumbers[]; //itemNum
$zeroQty[]; //quantity order of zero
$sixQty[]; //quantity order of six
//etc
```

This means I need to initialize multiple arrays even when they may not even be used. It seems I can either have an obtuse SQL structure but a simple means of initializing things, or a simple SQL structure and an obtuse way of initializing things.

Comment: don't do that. `(itemNum, itemName, itemPrice, strength)` would be a better way. if you end up with some other flavor that strength `one`, `seven`, and `eighty`, you'd have to add more columns to your table and waste a lot of space. a generic strength field lets you have **ANY** strength you want. Then you put in an itemID field for those records, and every strength gets its own automatic ID and problem solved.

Comment: I guess you need to look into what data normalization is, this is what ZZ- bb implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question about design or implementation? (Now it seems you are asking both.)

You could store your cigarette data into two tables.

Table `item` (if strength doesn't affect price, PK: itemNum):

```
itemNum  itemName itemPrice
--------------------------
   1     Banana    10.99
   2     Cherry    10.99
```

Table `itemStock` (PK: itemNum, itemConc):

```
itemNum  itemConc  stockRemaining
-------------------------------
   1     0         0
   1     6         5
   1     12        7
   1     18        25
   2     0         3
   2     6         10
...
```

Now you can easily check the stock for each item and add new strengths. If the item price varies for each strength you can move it into itemStock table. Or add it into a new table if you want to control the for different cigarette box sizes.

And your shopping cart could contain `(itemNum, itemName, itemPrice, strength)` like Marc B suggested.

Was this what you were looking for?